# Intent для доступа к файлам в Android10

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Моя программа использует файлы пользователя (фотографии и музыку). Для их выбора я использую Intent.

```
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "mp3"), GET_MP3);
```

Я сохраняю пути к файлам для дальнейшей работы с ними. Получаю их так.

```
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor == null){
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //int count = cursor.getCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){
            Log.d("m1", cursor.getColumnName(i) + " - " + cursor.getString(i));
        }
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        if(idx > -1)
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        cursor.close();
    }
```

Но в андроид 10 я более не могу получить абсолютный путь. Копировать файлы себе в программу локально сильно увеличивает размер.

Существует ли другой способ сохранить ссылку на файлы для дальнейшего использования??

Comment: Способ такой: забыть про файлы, сохранять и использовать сами контент-ссылки (`Uri`). Чтобы приложение могло их использовать после перезагрузки, нужно запросить удержание прав доступа: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru#permissions

Comment: Огромное спасибо, будет ли продолжать работать сие чудо на андроид Q ?

Comment: Будет, пока уровень секьюрной паранойи не заставит манагеров гугла выдумать новый способ извращения.

Comment: woesss ваш ответ самый точный, решил использовать его. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Android 10 вы больше не можете напрямую обращаться к файлам на устройстве. Google отказываются от этого подхода т.к. это не секьюрно.

Если вы хотите работать с файлами то у вас есть несколько путей:

- [Media Store](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) - для работы с медиа файлами, такими как аудио, видео, фото.
- [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru) - для работы с файлами други поставщиков. Файлами которые шарят другие приложения и которые находятся в общем доступе у пользователя на устройстве.
- [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) - для работы с внутренними файлами приложения.

Comment: спасибо, Google очень отрезвляет. Придется купить телефон с андроид 10 для тестов:(